# Java web application slack integration to send alerts

Tags: java, spring-boot, slack, slack-api

We are currently developing a web application in Java with spring-boot, there is an requirement to allow the application to be able to send alerts to customers slack groups, if any are being created.

From what I read, I think the website should be integrated with slack similar to how google drive/github integration works.

But I can't figure out how to proceed and which API to use (Web/Events), also how does the authentication part work, do I need to ask the customer to provide webhooks or can I use OAuth.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for, slack has great documentation for creating apps 
https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack.

My earlier understanding was that slack apps are for internal organization use, they have documentation to setup OAuth.